# Why is SQL Server 2012 applying stop words that are NOT present in our custom stoplist?

Tags: sql-server

We use SQL Server 2012 `CONTAINSTABLE` full text search queries and we want certain words to be found: 'noord', 'oost', 'zuid', 'west'. The example is for Dutch but the issue is not language specific.

For example 'noord' is not found because this is a word in the Dutch system stoplist. This is understandable.

We therefore created a custom stoplist from the system stoplist, and removed the offending stop words: 'noord', 'west' and 'zuid' in this case.

Queries containing search term 'noord' now yield results, as expected. However search term 'west' still yields no results.

Despite correctly using the custom stoplist, rebuilding the full text catalog and so on SQL Server still applies stop word 'west'. Why?

Answer (score 4):

In short this seems to be caused by other stop words: 'zuidzuidwest' and 'westzuidwest'. SQL-Server applies some splitting mechanism, causing 'west' to still be a stop word. Possibly it uses a word breaker, or it applies the system stoplist to split words in the custom stoplist.

The measure taken is to remove stop words 'zuidzuidwest' and 'westzuidwest' from the custom stoplist. This solves the issue.

Below some details.

Whether words are in the system stoplist can be established using the following query.

```
SELECT * FROM sys.fulltext_system_stopwords WHERE language_id=1043
AND stopword IN ('noord', 'oost', 'zuid', 'west');
```

This yields

```
noord  1043
west   1043
zuid   1043
```

Create a custom stoplist from the system stoplist:

```
CREATE FULLTEXT STOPLIST CustomStoplist FROM SYSTEM STOPLIST;
```

Establish the stoplist id:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.fulltext_stoplists;
```

Yields (in this case) stop list id 6 to be used in the queries below. Remove offending stop words:

```
ALTER FULLTEXT STOPLIST CustomStoplist DROP 'noord' LANGUAGE 1043;
ALTER FULLTEXT STOPLIST CustomStoplist DROP 'west' LANGUAGE 1043;
ALTER FULLTEXT STOPLIST CustomStoplist DROP 'zuid' LANGUAGE 1043;
```

The following query shows that SQL-Server will still filter 'zuid' and 'west':

```
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_fts_parser('"noord" or "oost" or "zuid" or "west"', 1043, 6, 0);
```

This shows that 'zuid' and 'west' are noise words, despite the words being removed from the custom stoplist.

```
Exact Match  noord
Exact Match  oost
Noise Word   zuid
Noise Word   west
```

Take the above measure:

```
ALTER FULLTEXT STOPLIST CustomStoplist DROP 'zuidzuidwest' LANGUAGE 1043;
ALTER FULLTEXT STOPLIST CustomStoplist DROP 'westzuidwest' LANGUAGE 1043;
```

Repeat the dm_fts_parser query: problem solved.

In order to find all composed words that could interfere:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.fulltext_stopwords WHERE stoplist_id=6
AND language_id=1043
AND (stopword LIKE '%noord%' OR stopword LIKE '%oost%'
OR stopword LIKE '%zuid%' OR stopword LIKE '%west%');
```

Yields for example 'zuidwest' and 'zuidzuidoost'. To be sure words like these can also be dropped from the custom stoplist.

For completeness a search query. Note this query cannot be run because table Contents and columns Nr and Title are application specific.

```
SELECT c.Nr, c.Title FROM CONTAINSTABLE(Contents, (Title),
'"noord" or "oost" or "zuid" or "west"') x JOIN Contents c
ON x.[KEY]=c.Nr ORDER BY c.Nr;
```

The query yields a certain number of hits. After dropping stop word 'zuidzuidwest' the number of hits increases, which was the original goal. After dropping stop word 'westzuidwest' the number of hits increases even more. Thereafter dropping additional stop words like 'zuidwest' does not result in additional hits.